# compiling cpp wasm module using skia library face to an error

Tags: c++, webassembly, skia

I'm trying to use SKIA lib in my WASM solution. first I Compiled Skia to wasm bitcode using bellow config:

```
/bin/gn gen ./out/Build-wasm-Release/Release --args="cc=\"emcc\" extra_cflags_cc=[\"-frtti\",\"-s\",\"USE_FREETYPE=1\"] cxx=\"em++\" extra_cflags=[\"-Wno-unknown-warning-option\",\"-s\",\"USE_FREETYPE=1\",\"-s\",\"USE_LIBPNG=1\"] \
is_debug=false \
is_official_build=true \
is_component_build=false \
target_cpu=\"wasm\" \
\
skia_use_egl=false \
skia_use_vulkan=false \
skia_use_libwebp=false \
skia_use_libpng=true \
skia_use_lua=false \
skia_use_dng_sdk=false \
skia_use_fontconfig=false \
skia_use_libjpeg_turbo=false \
skia_use_libheif=false \
skia_use_expat=false \
skia_use_vulkan=false \
skia_use_freetype=false \
skia_use_icu=false \
skia_use_expat=false \
skia_use_piex=false \
skia_use_zlib=true \
skia_enable_gpu=true \
skia_enable_pdf=false"
```

it successfully compiled, when I try to compile my own code using:

```
em++ multiply.cpp -o multiply.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_float_multiply','_float_multiply_array','_sample_array_rtn','_sample_array_float_rtn','_msd_main']"-s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]'  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s USE_LIBPNG=1 -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=0 -I$SKIAPATH/include/ -I$SKIAPATH/include/gpu -I$SKIAPATH/include/core -I$SKIAPATH/include/config -I$SKIAPATH/include/c -L$SKIAPATH/out/Build-wasm-Release/Release -I$SKIAPATH -lskia
```

I got bellow this error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Invalid SIMD cast between items of different bit sizes!
```

Comment: Still looking for an answer?

Comment: Have you tried passing the `-msimd128` flag to emcc? Since your error is specific to SIMD, this flag might help.